# Ruby on rails: count the number of records per category after filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Ransack search form on browse.html.erb which filters articles by title and category. When i first enter the browse page without doing any search, i want a list of all categories with the count of articles belonging to the category to be rendered on the sidebar. After I submit a search, i want the list of categories and article count to be updated based on the search results.

I am unable to understand why this error occurs:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Article:0x007f1e60f193e0>
```

browse.html.erb

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <p><%= link_to category.name, browse_articles_path(category: category.name) %></p>
    <p><%= category.articles.select{|article| article.where(title == params[:q][:title_cont])}.count %></p>
  <% end %>
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
  def browse
    @q = Article.ransack(params[:q])
    @articles = @q.result.includes(:categories, :users)
    if params[:q][:title_cont] == present?
      @categories = Category.joins(:articles).where('article.title LIKE ?', params[:q][:title_cont]).uniq
    else
      @categories = Category.includes(:articles).order('name ASC').all
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diana!

You are using select on articles array and pass `article` variable to a block. `article` variable contains just a plain Article. This object doesn't have `.where` method.

Rewrite:

```
category.articles.select{|article| article.where(title == params[:q][:title_cont])}.count
```

To:

```
category.articles.ransack(params[:q]).result.count
```

But this code is still can be refactored and improved a lot. Can you share a full view please?

**Edited**

```
category.articles.where(title: params[:q][:title_cont]).count
```

Is a bad solution, because it will check for articles with fully equal title, while you are looking for articles which title contains substring of `params[:q][:title_cont]`.

Comment: Are you sure @diana is looking for a matching substring? He would have to use a wildcard if that's the case.

Comment: I can't be sure, but ransack title_cont is a wildcard match. If she was looking for exact match, she would go with title_eq.

PS: I am not sure, but I think that Diana is a girl :)

Answer (score 1):

In Rails `where` is an `ActiveRecord` method, a query interface for retrieving data from your database. In your example you'd have to do this instead:

```
<%= category.articles.where(title: params[:q][:title_cont]).count %>
```

[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

**WHY?**

You are trying to execute where condition on Article object,Not on Article relation.

***Either replace***

```
<p><%= category.articles.select{|article| article.where(title == params[:q][:title_cont])}.count %></p>
```

***with***

```
<p><%= category.articles.select{|article| article.class.where(title == params[:q][:title_cont])}.count %></p>
```

## OR

Right approach

```
<p><%= category.articles.where(title: params[:q][:title_cont]).count %></p>
```